# White Pine load bearing capacity

Tags: load-bearing, load, pine

How much load can a 4 x 6 solid white pine support on an 8ft span (anchored a both ends)
The normal snow load in this area is 125psf.

Comment: You have to decide your maximum deflection.

Comment: A) That's a _lot_ of snow, and B) what else is it supporting?